# Getting projections from MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

I have a Linq query with a `select`, from my Linq query provider it I get an *expression tree* containing a `MethodCallExpression`, but just how can I get the select *projections* from the `MethodCallExpression`?

```
    internal static object Execute(Expression expression, bool isEnumerable)
    {
        var whereExpression = expression as MethodCallExpression;
        if (whereExpression == null) throw new InvalidProgramException("Error");

        foreach (var arg in whereExpression.Arguments)
        {
            if (arg is UnaryExpression)
            {
                var unaryExpression = arg as UnaryExpression;

                var lambdaExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as LambdaExpression;
                if (lambdaExpression == null) continue;

                // Here I would like to get the select projections, in this example the "word" projection ...
```

Query may look like:

```
var queryable = new MyQueriableClass();

var query = from thing in queryable 
            where thing.id == 1
            select word;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear what you are doing, **but**

```
// note the AsQueryable! Otherwise there is no
// Expression tree!
var words = new List<string>() { "an", "apple", "a", "day" }.AsQueryable();

// Note that even IQueryable<string> query = words; 
// is a perfectly good query without a projection!
// The query 
// from word in words where word.Length > 0 select word
// doesn't have a select too (try looking at the 
// expression tree... The select has been elided)
// The projection if not present is implicit, the
// whole object.
var query = from word in words
            select word;

var exp = query.Expression;
var methodCallExpression = exp as MethodCallExpression;

if (methodCallExpression != null)
{
    MethodInfo method = methodCallExpression.Method;

    if (method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && method.Name == "Select")
    {
        var source = methodCallExpression.Arguments[0];
        var selector = methodCallExpression.Arguments[1];

        // The selector parameter passed to Select is an
        // Expression.Quote(subexpression),
        // where subexpression is the lambda expression
        // word => word here
        if (selector.NodeType != ExpressionType.Quote)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        UnaryExpression unary = (UnaryExpression)selector;
        Expression operand = unary.Operand;

        if (operand.NodeType != ExpressionType.Lambda)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)operand;

        // This is the "thing" that returns the result
        Expression body = lambda.Body; 
    }
}
```

The `body` at the end should be what you want (or perhaps the `lambda` just before the end). Note the comments at the beginning of the code block.

Comment: Using your approach then `body` is `thing.id == 1` in my code, not the "word" projection I was hoping for.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen I was just adding a comment... *The query `from word in words where word.Length > 0 select word` doesn't have a select too* (so clearly doesn't yours)... If you use the functional notation, it will be clear why: `query.Where(word => word.Length > 0)` where is the `Select` here? there isn't!

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Yes... But the problem is that it isn't clear what you want to obtain... For example: `query.Select(x => new { Foo = x }).Where(x => x.Foo.id == 1).Select(x => new { Bar = x.Foo }` here there are two projections... whatever you want to obtain is complex

Comment: @IngeHenriksen `query.Select(x => new { Foo = x }).Where(x => x.Foo.id == 1)` Here instead the `Select` is "hidden" behind the `Where`...

Comment: I see that `method.Name == "Where"` in my case. How do I "unhide" the select?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75598/discussion-between-xanatos-and-inge-henriksen).